# undefined symbol in node.js C++ addon under Linux, why?

Tags: javascript, c++, linux, node.js, v8

I'm a newbie of writing C++ addons in node.js.

And this is my module:

```
$ npm install simpleini
```

It's based on *miniini-0.9*. And my source is under `src/simpleIni.cc`.
I've tried this module under Windows, OS X, Linux (Debian).
It works well under Windows and OS X.

But when I ran in Linux, it appears that:

```
node: symbol lookup err: .../simpleIni.node: undefined symbol: _ZNK10INISection10ReadStringEPKcRS1_
```

Why?

Comment: er... we would need to see a little more of your code than the name or your source file. I'm unsure about how node.js C++ addons are delivered.... but if you have dynamic library (in unix) you can use nm to verify whether the failing symbol is defined or undefined. Does this name INISession10 ReadString rings any bell? something that you've declared and forgotten to define?

Comment: sorry i've not pushed it to github yet. but you can get code through npm install. because it has more than one file. but my source file is just simpleIni.cc

Comment: Try removing the `inline` in `src/miniini-0.9/miniini/src/inisection.cpp` line 125....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some searching this is what I've found.

Doing:

```
$ nm -C build/Release/simpleIni.node  | grep ReadString
                 U INISection::ReadString(char const*, char const*&) const
00000000000032b0 t INISection::ReadString(char const*, char const*&) const [clone .part.11]
0000000000003f80 W INISection::ReadString(std::string const&, std::string&) const
00000000000081a0 T INISection::ReadStrings(char const*, char const**, unsigned int) const
0000000000008f20 T INISection::ReadStrings(std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&) const
000000000000bca0 r INISection::ReadString(char const*, char const*&) const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
000000000000b8a0 r INISection::ReadStrings(char const*, char const**, unsigned int) const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
```

So the key is the

```
                 U INISection::ReadString(char const*, char const*&) const
```

Which appears as undefined... Although there's another copy of the symbol

```
00000000000032b0 t INISection::ReadString(char const*, char const*&) const [clone .part.11]
```

Now we can search for this method in your code:

at src/miniini-0.9/miniini/include/inisection.h

```
class INISection
{
...
        bool ReadString(const char * const name, const char * & out) const;
}
```

And in src/miniini-0.9/miniini/src/inisection.cpp

```
inline bool INISection::ReadString(const char * name, const char * & out) const
{
...
}
```

Now the key is this inline. According to the C++ FAQ [How do you tell the compiler to make a member function inline?](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-member-fns)

> The reason you (almost always) put the definition (the {...} part) of
>   an inline function in a header file is to avoid “unresolved external”
>   errors from the linker. That error will occur if you put the inline
>   function’s definition in a .cpp file and if that function is called
>   from some other .cpp file.

removing the inline from the inisection.cpp
and rebuilding we can try again the nm

```
$ nm -C build/Release/simpleIni.node  | grep ReadString
00000000000069a0 T INISection::ReadString(char const*, char const*&) const
0000000000003f70 W INISection::ReadString(std::string const&, std::string&) const
00000000000080e0 T INISection::ReadStrings(char const*, char const**, unsigned int) const
0000000000008d20 T INISection::ReadStrings(std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&) const
000000000000bc20 r INISection::ReadString(char const*, char const*&) const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
000000000000b7e0 r INISection::ReadStrings(char const*, char const**, unsigned int) const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
```

This time there are no undefined symbols and the ReadString appears only once.

Comment: So can I move the defination of the inline function to the header file instead?

Comment: @XadillaX... if you want to keep it inline, you should.